# SQL - Order by Max() on Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I gather that I cannot get the MAX() on some alias that I have in the select statement in sql queries?

Example:

```
Select  
    CASE WHEN CompletionDate IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(d, CreatedDate, CompletionDate) ELSE NULL END AS DaysLong
from CombinedMastervw 
WHERE CreatedDate Between '03/01/2019 23:59:59.991' AND '04/01/2019 23:59:59.991'
ORDER BY MAX(dayslong)
```

Thus my question is on `MAX(dayslong)`,  do I have to end up doing a Max with the same code in the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Do you want the max value, or do you want to order all the rows? I'm guessing you want to order by dayslong descending (so highest value first)?

Comment: What does `ORDER BY MAX(dayslong)` even mean?

Comment: I don't even need the Max …  I wasn't doing it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the alias.

Try:

> ORDER BY dayslong

Max(dayslong) would return the single maximum value in the table you are selecting, so you cannot order by it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `max()` use `top (1)` and `order by`:

```
Select TOP (1) DATEDIFF(day, CreatedDate, CompletionDate)  DaysLong
from CombinedMastervw 
WHERE CreatedDate >= '2019-03-01' AND
      CreatedDate < '2019-04-02'
ORDER BY dayslong DESC;
```

I changed the date comparisons so they are for full days.  If you really want a few seconds before midnight, then you can change back to your version.

Comment: Ok cool,  but if I want more than 1 result, then how do I do it?

Comment: @ChadJacobs . . . Just remove the `TOP (1)`.  The use of `MAX()` suggested that you wanted one result.